# How can I use normal CAN with CAN FD?

Tags: stm32, embedded, can, nxp

I'm working with i.MX6ULL not supporting CAN FD but other CAN nodes supports. How can I use normal CAN on this bus without making any hardware changes?

I need to fix CAN to CAN FD communication compatibility.

Comment: Unless the CAN 2.0 device can pull itself off the bus, it will not play nicely with FD frames. Check if the NXP CAN peripheral has Partial Networking (PN).